How can I use a custom Jinja2 template function which relies on a variable in the function calling "render"
I am trying to figure out how to pass a variable into a custom template function and so far I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.  The idea is that I am going to have a template be passed in and I want to have it call a custom Jinja2 function.  I need to pass down a variable to the custom function.  This will run in a Celery job, but for the sake of this question, I have simplified the issue.
Something similar to:
import jinja2

def calling_function():
   var1 = "joe"
   environment = jinja2.Environment()
   func_dict = {
   "do_it": do_it
   }
   environment.globals.update(func_dict)
   output = environment.from_string("{{ do_it() }}").render()
   print(output)

def do_it():
    return "yes: %s" % (var1)


calling_function()

I get a Name error which makes sense because it is out of scope:
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'vars'?
If I put var1 outside of the scope:
import jinja2

var1 = ""

def calling_function():
   var1 = "joe"
   environment = jinja2.Environment()
   func_dict = {
   "do_it": do_it
   }
   environment.globals.update(func_dict)
   output = environment.from_string("{{ do_it() }}").render()
   print(output)

def do_it():
    return "yes: %s" % (var1)

output:
yes:
The script completes but var1 is still empty.  I would like to be able to get a variable down to do_it without having to manipulate or have anything more than {{ do_it() }}.  I don't know if I need to pass the variable into the template and then pull it back out?

You can pass variables to .render, making them accessible in the rendering code:
import jinja2

def do_it(var1):
    return "yes: %s" % (var1)

def calling_function():
   environment = jinja2.Environment()
   output = environment.from_string("{{ do_it(var1) }}").render(do_it = do_it, var1 = "joe")
   print(output)

calling_function()

yes: joe

If you don't want explicit reference to var1 in template, you can create a partial function with preapplies arguments:
import jinja2
from functools import partial

def do_it(var1):
    return "yes: %s" % (var1)

def calling_function():
   var1 = "joe"
   environment = jinja2.Environment()
   do_it2 = partial(do_it, var1)
   output = environment.from_string("{{ do_it() }}").render(do_it = do_it2)
   print(output)

calling_function()

In short, template needs to be passed value for var1 one way or another, be it directly or indirectly, in order to be able to use it in creating template.

Is it possible to do it without requiring the do_it(var1) portion?  I don't want the template to need to pass back the variable as it would complicate the template design.

I'd say pulling random variables from different file makes it more complicated than passing them explicitly.

I don't mind passing the variable in the calling_function.  The idea is that the template is being made by someone else, and I am trying to shield them from the complications of how it is working under the hood.

@user25432002 I've added a version that uses only {{ do_it() }}, but, in the end, you need to pass the variable to template one way or another.

I think that works!!!!! it is simple, I would never have thought of that!
